# How do I create a user profile on visual studio asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to create a user profile for when users login. At the moment, I have created a login and reg system and created a session[Username] so it finds out who's currently logged in. I can also log out.

How do I create a user profile page so when users login, they can see their first name, last name, address, phone number etc. 
I have thought of using grid view but releases every data in the table which is more of an admins table or can it be altered so it searches by the username from the session that has been created?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class UserPanel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Session["Username"] != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Welcome, " + Session["Username"].ToString() ;


        }
        else {

            Label1.Text = "Please make sure to login in order to via your details";
            detailBtn.Visible = false;
            bookingBtn.Visible = false;
        }


    }

    protected void detailBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // I have texts boxes for each field. 
Textbox1 for FirstName
TextBox2 for Second name


    }�
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using the built-in ASP identity system?

Comment: It's confusing and it's been messed up. Just need something simple

Comment: Simple isn't necessarily secure, and even though you may not be securing much important data on your site, remember that most users use the same passwords for everything. Somebody hacking your site (even if its just you and your friends) and getting your email/password may be able to access other accounts, such as bank accounts.

Comment: I understand. This is just school work. Won't be releasing for the public and we don't get marked for security. So I just want this to function any way possible. Thanks for your concern